# Android - Erro NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

Estou recebendo o seguinte erro aleatoriamente, ou seja, dá erro umas vezes e outras não:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at pt.cartuxa.Login.onCreate(Login.java:62)
```

A minha linha 62 é a seguinte:

```
password.setImeActionLabel(getString(R.string.keyboard_enter), KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER);
```

Código completo:

```
public class Login  extends Activity {

    EditText username, password;
    Editable user_input, pass_input;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // SETTERS
        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_login_user);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_login_pass);

        // VIEW
        setContentView(R.layout.login_layout);

        // VIEW CONFIGS
        password.setImeActionLabel(getString(R.string.keyboard_enter), KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER);

    }
}
```

Criei a linha 62 para alterar o texto do botão Enter para "Login" mas acontece que quando corro a aplicação, umas vezes inicializa correctamente e outras vezes bloqueia nessa linha dando o erro descrito em cima.

Como posso fazer para evitar esse erro?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema é que está buscando as `View's` do seu layout antes de adicionar o próprio à `Activity`, usando o método `setContentView`. Quando você faz isso, ele não vai encontrar as `View's` que esta pedindo no `findViewById`, gerando o `NullPointerException`.

Chame o `setContentView` antes de qualquer manipulação de `View`, após o `super.onCreate()` é claro.

Seu código deve ficar:

```
public class Login  extends Activity {

    EditText username, password;
    Editable user_input, pass_input;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Adicione o layout antes de qualquer manipulacao relativa ao mesmo
        // VIEW
        setContentView(R.layout.login_layout);

        // SETTERS
        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_login_user);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_login_pass);

        // Restante do seu código
    }
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, era exactamente esse o problema